# Android emulator unistalls application after the app is closed, but I need to test serialization

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am trying to implement serialization for an email application on the android (stroring username, password, server etc.), but in order to test it I have to close the application in the emulator and then re-open it to ensure that it looks and finds the file with the serialized objects.  The problem is that when I close the application on the emulator uninstalls the application.  I close the application with the finish() function.  Any inklings as to why this happens?  And it wasn't doing it until further along in my development stage.  Thank you for any help provided.

Comment: If you put your app's icon on the homescreen, click on it and then click BACK (to close the app), the icon disappears?

Comment: Sounds very wierd Are you sure it is uninstalling, have you looked in the apps drawer?

Answer (score 0):

When you close an android app in the emulator, it does not uninstall it.
Also, when you force your application to finish using the finish() method, that only closes the application, and will not uninstall it either.

Eventually the problem is in something else, either in something you added elsewhere in your application's code, or in another app that you have installed in the virtual device you are using for testing.

Also, every time you launch your app from within the eclipse environment, it should only install itself if the version being launched is different than the one already installed in the device (if one is installed).

Try making a new virtual device with a fresh SD card too, just in case, and try putting your app in it alone to see if it behaves as it should.